# Laravel 5.0 TokenMismatchException with ajax login

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I am developing a web application with laravel 5.0, php 5.5 on a debian 7 server.

this website allows user to login through a login modal (ajax login). but...

I keep getting this exception

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 47
```

I know story about csrf_token() must in the form and X-CSRF-TOKEN for ajax post. I have tried every thing but still no solution.

the interesting thing is, that happened only if you visit the site at first time, on homepage or any page directly. When you visit a member area, and laravel will redirect you to homepage with auth errors, after that, you will never get tokenmismatchexception again, the same login modal works as a sun shines.

any suggestion

UPDATE:

here are the codes:

in the Header I have include the csrf_code() already:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and in the form (actually is optional, because X-CSRF-TOKEN is already setup)

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

route:

```
Route::post('/login', ['as' => 'auth.login', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postSignin']);
```

VerifyCsrfToken.php for debugging.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->isReading($request) || $this->tokensMatch($request)) {
        return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
    }

    throw new TokenMismatchException;
}

public function tokensMatch($request)
{
    $token = $request->input('_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');

    if (!$token && $header = $request->header('X-XSRF-TOKEN')) {
        $token = $this->encrypter->decrypt($header);
    }
    \Clockwork::info($request->session()->token());
    //\Clockwork::info(\Session::token());
    \Clockwork::info($token);
    //return StringUtils::equals($request->session()->token(), $token);
    return StringUtils::equals(\Session::token(), $token);
}
```

Jquery Ajax setup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-XSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

output:
[image]

Comment: `"I have tried every thing"`. What have you tried?

Comment: override handle and tokensMatch methods, change $request->session()->token() to Session::token(), also in the meta tag replace csrf_token() with Session::token(), but still no same token while posting.

Comment: Are you adding the token to your ajax HTTP post request?

Comment: yes I did, with log I can see that $request->session()->token() is not same with token from ajax which also generate by laravel self.

Comment: Well, seems like you've tried the usual solutions to this problem. It's going to be really hard to help you without seeing any code. I could sit here and ask you questions all day long until we narrow it down, but posting your code would save us both all that time.

Comment: thanks! I have post my code now, as you said, that was a usual solutions.

Comment: How about the code you use to actually add the csrf token into your request? Are you doing it globally or in the ajax request?

Comment: the jquery code is added, is laravel refresh session::token() by each request for guest user?

Comment: the guy who gives downvote, please explain the reason... we are trying to find a solution, if this is for you a simple thing, just give your solution... let we give you more points

Comment: @Jeemusu the problem is solved, thanks for spending time

Answer (score 2):

Yes Finally fixed, The reason was because there was two blank lines at the beginning of website. in the content blades I have used

```
@extends('layouts/main')...@show
```

for showing layouts. the @show causes that two blank lines, remove @show and the blank lines are gone. for whatever reason, that breaks all cookies on the site and Laravel is unable to create a session.

Answer (score 0):

your all code is going good ..

You can try this ...

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-XSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
});
```

move this code just after calling  jquery file ...

actually when page is going load then html dom loading after runing this code . you should do that your this code should run after loaded html dom .

i had this same problem in my website .